# How can I solve NoneType object has no attribute 'text' in Kivy?

Tags: python, variables, properties, kivy, mobile-application

**.py**

```
class dfpScreen(Screen):
    inputdf = ObjectProperty(None)
    inp = ObjectProperty(None)
    #d = StringProperty()
    #pval = StringProperty()
    def getvalue(self):
        d=float(str(self.inputdf.text))
        print(d)
```

**.kv**

```
<dfpScreen>:
    name:'dfp'
    GridLayout:
        inputdf:inputdf
        inp:inp
        cols:2
        Label:
            text: "Df (Degree of Freedom):"
        TextInput:
            id:inputdf
            multiline:False
        Label:
            text: "P value:"
        TextInput:
            id:inp
            multiline:False
        Button:
            text: "Back to Input"
            on_release:
                app.root.current='mainwin'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        Button:
            text: "Check"
            on_release:
                root.getvalue()
                root.ibtn()
                app.root.current='calcwin'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
```

When the button gets pressed, it should read the text in the text input box, but it does not work. I have similar codes, and they worked. I do not know why this one does not. Here is a similar code I made that works.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    ans=StringProperty()
    adding = ObjectProperty(None)
    adding2 = StringProperty()
    deleting = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        try:
            lis.append(float(self.adding.text))
            #print(lis)
        except:
            pass

<MainScreen>:
    id:first
    name:'mainwin'
    adding:adding
    adding3:adding3
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: adding
            multiline:False
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y":0.75}
            font_size: (40)
```

What is the difference between the two codes?
Thank you,

P.S.
It solved. I do not know why I did not try this:

```
on_release:
    root.getvaluebtn(inputdf.text)
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

missing init for callses. if you are creating object for classes its required to init the variables. or have a api to init.

```
    class dfpScreen(Screen):
        def __init__ (self) : 
            self.inputdf = ObjectProperty(None)
            self.inp = ObjectProperty(None)

        def getvalue(self):
            if self.inputdf != None:
                d=float(str(self.inputdf.text))
                print(d)
```

Comment: It showed TypeErrorr: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder'

Comment: Sorry for another question, how could I solve this problem? thank you,

Comment: we need to accept args for obj, def __init__(self, **kwargs): , also may need to pass it to parent class screen (optional named arg for parent). "super().__init__(**kwargs)" or "super(dfpScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)"